# Standard practice to define HttpHeaders()? One common function to define new HttpHeaders() or should it be define under each function?

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular-httpclient, custom-headers

What is the standard practice to set custom headers in Angular?
To have a global **setHeader function in a service file**, where every get request calls this function

app.component.ts

```
 getData() {
        const url = `myurl`;
        var param = {"data1": this.data1,"data2": this.data2}
        var headerObj = {"header1": this.header1,"header2": this.header2,}
        this.dataService.getRequest(url, param, headerObj)
            .subscribe((data) => {});
    }
```

dataService.ts

```
setHeaders(header) {
    var httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    header.forEach((key, value) => {
        httpHeaders = httpHeaders.append(key, value);
    });
    return httpHeaders
}
getRequest(endPoint: String, param: any, header: any) {
    const httpHeaders = this.setHeaders(header);
    return this.http.get<any>(url, {
        headers: httpHeaders,
        params: param
    })
}
```

**OR**
Passing header from **app.component** function into **dataService.ts** get request function

app.component.ts

```
getData() {
    const url = `myurl`;
    var param = {"data1": this.data1,"data2": this.data2,}
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('header1', this.header1)
    .set('header2', this.header2);
    this.dataService.getRequest(url, param, headers)
    .subscribe((data) => {});
}
```

dataService.ts

```
getRequest(endPoint: string, params: any, headers: HttpHeaders) {
    return this.http.get<any>(endPoint, {
        headers: headers,
        params: param
    })
}
```

Comment: hi, you can create interceptor to handle all requests and attach headers to them. You can read more in this article https://medium.com/angular-shots/shot-3-how-to-add-http-headers-to-every-request-in-angular-fab3d10edc26

Comment: @Belouccio Hi, interceptors are used for global headers like authentication tokens, right?
But if we have a header for a specific service call.
**Where should we define new HttpHeaders();**
In app component and pass it in a function call 
Or should I define it in data service file

Comment: sorry, I misread your question) I think it’s more correct to write in a service file, because the component should mainly have display logic, and work with data should be done in the service in order to comply with the mvc pattern.

Comment: also if you will use your service in other components, you will not have to duplicate this method in them